# No activity found to handle Intent android.intent.action.REQUEST_TANGO_PERMISSION (has extras)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-project-tango

I'm new to Project Tango and for now I'm trying to run the demo apps provided but I keep on bumping into this error message in both the motion tracking and area learning demo projects because I can't see that action be declared in the manifest file. I know this error complains about either the activity not being declared in the manifest but it is there. Do I need to have anything else installed on the device so this line doesn't make the app crash?

> 11-04 13:04:21.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2867):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.projecttango.motiontrackingjava/com.projecttango.motiontrackingjava.StartActivity}:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.REQUEST_TANGO_PERMISSION (has
>   extras) }

This is how StartActivity is being declared on the manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you pasted in is correct. The issue seems to be an incorrect version of the TangoCore service. Please try to update your software via OTA.

Edit for more information :

The activity that is missing is a service that handles permissions needed by the Tango service, named Permission Manager. After updating ,via Settings -> About tablet -> System updates, you should have a this new application on your device. If you don't have this application you will not be able to run any Tango applications, as they all prompt the user for permission to run.

The new permissions are for Motion Tracking, ADF saving/loading, and ADF import/export.

More information can be found at the following link. Cheers!
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/java-user-permissions

Comment: If this answer had a little more **why**, a little more explanation of what is going on with this version skew, it would be a fine answer. Please consider editing it, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Apologies, I have added more information to the comment.

Comment: At the time of the post, I tried updating since my own suspicion was the same, however, the device kept on saying it was up to date. So I decided to do a factory reset and then I got the OTA update notification and now everything is working correctly. Thanks Chase Cobb.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth noting that you can get into a state where one app will surface this message, but another won't.  The solution is the same (OTA update).

I think the case where an app has been deployed, and run previously, then you wipe the machine (and don't get all updates), the previous apps might still run in debug, whereas any new ones one.

Either way, OTA update every time.